# Integral of a function is not affected by altering the function values at zero-measure set

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm studying about Fourier analysis from a book Fourier analysis and its applications, Folland 1992 and I have one point in the source I need clarification about: On page 69 it is stated that:

"The integral of a function is not affected by altering the value of the function at a finite number of points, so if $f$ is a function on $[a, b]$ that is zero except at a finite number of points, then $||f||  = 0$ ($||f||$ is the norm) although $f$ is not the zero function."

$$||f|| = \sqrt{\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 \:dx}$$

My question is why?

**UPDATE**:

Is this the reason:

If $f$ is zero elsewhere on interval $[a,b]$ except on point $n$, then:

$$\int_a^nf(x)\:dx + \int_n^nf(x)\:dx + \int_n^bf(x)\:dx = 0 + F(n)-F(n) + 0 = 0$$

Comment: Have you tried anything to convince yourself it is true?

Comment: +1 I haven't done any calculus, only tried to think about it...if integral is defined to be an infinite sum...then summing an infinite amount of zeros and few other non-zero values shouldn't be zero right?...

Comment: Integral is not an infinite sum of values $f(x)$. It is an infinite sum of $f(x)dx$ where $dx$ is the witdth of an infinitesimal rectangle around $x$ (this allows to relate area under the graph and integral).

Comment: Since you are dealing with Fourier analysis, the preferred integreal concept should be Lebesgue integral, not Riemann integral. In that context, "finitely many points" can be replaced with "zero-measure set" which includes "countably infinitely many points".

Comment: The integral is the area in between the graphic of the function, and the horizontal axis. Now, the area of a straight line segment is $0$, since it can be imagined like a rectangle with $0$ withdraw and finite height. If from the area of the integral we were to subtract a finite number of line segments, each with $0$ area, what would we get ? Would it not be the exact same value as before the subtraction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of a positive function should give an idea of the area below its graph.

Intuitively, if you take the function for which $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$, and $f(0)=1$ (you can generalize this by additivity to a finite number of non-zero values), it should be clear that its area cannot be positive.

This is formally described by the [Lebesgue Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) (the Riemann Integration that you may have already seen does not make sense for such a function).

**EDIT** (after seeing OP's update): you cannot use the fact that $$\int_n^n f(t)dt=F(n)-F(n)$$ if $f$ is not continuous (which is precisely the case here). However, for the Lebesgue integral, $\int_n^nf(t)dt$ is always $0$ because the Borel set $\{n\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.